# How to connect a SpringBoot project to SonarQube

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, sonarqube

I am trying to connect my Spring Boot application to SonarCloud, using a maven plugin for it. Concretely, I am trying to run (I got these instructions from SonarCloud tutorial):

`mvn sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.organization=myacconunt-github \
  -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
  -Dsonar.login=mygeneratedtoken`

Everything seems good but I got this error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project demo: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator. -`

I have been checking Sonar permissions for my user and everything looks good. I think my user has permissions, since I have another project from the same GitHub account working and being analysing by Sonar. Do you have similar problems to that one?

Comment: Did you try to update your token?

Comment: Chances are that you are using an groupId:artifactId that already exists on SonarCloud. Can you edit your question to tell which groupId and artifactId are specified in your main POM file?

Comment: you are absolutely right! I changed the `artifactId` and it started to work as usual. Is there a way to check which `groupId:artifactId` are published in Sonar in order to avoid this error for other users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Fabrice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976155/fabrice-sonarsource-team) I managed to solve that issue. It turned out that I was using a `groupId:artifactId` which was already used in SonarCloud. So just changing either `groupId` or `artifactId` worked.